# Mobile iOS usage tracking

Tags: ios, mobile, tracking, heatmap, tap

I'm currently looking for a way to track basic user data for mobile iOS application:

- how many times the app was launched
- what was the average/by session time spent in total while using app
- what was the average/by session time spent on particular screen

Additionally, I'd like the solution to:

- display a heatmaps or click/tap/maps (clickstreams), to show how users tried to interact with the interface
- generate visit graphs (user started from this screen, then went to this screen, etc.)

The most important requirement is that this is for internal application testing (nothing malicious), and **we want to categorize data by user logged in (so that we can gather data per user, not some general average).**

Can anyone recommend a suitable tool? Price or paid, doesn't matter. Is Google Analytics up for the job, or do we need something else?

Answer (score 1):

Youve got several options to track the user behavior in the app. You can use frameworks like :

- Flurry     (http://www.flurry.com/)
- Mixpanel   (http://mixpanel.com/)
- Localytics (http://www.localytics.com/)
- Google analytics

Im pretty sure there are more. Flurry is free (for now but you have some special paid features) and it´s broadly used. It´s the framework I use the most for my apps in these moments but it will depend of the client and the information you want to track. You can track events, events with information, see the stats of use, how the user has used the application, find dead holes in your app and broadly speaking, have a general idea about how your application has been used. The other frameworks are not free and you have to pay for the services but you can always use a trial version to see if this is what you want or not. Ive used localytics and its nice.
Ive tried all of them, and there are pros and cons, but to get a general idea about your application, everyone serves. Regarding heatmaps, Im not sure about that, I mean if some of the frameworks offer a solution like that, but you can always build your reports with the provided information (I know it´s not a straightforward thing or a 5 minutes thing).

Take a look, compare and decide which one can fit the best for you.

Comment: Thanks. I know that these solutions exist. I was asking particularly whether any of these cover my needs exactly - to avoid cumbersome testing one by one.

Comment: All the things you want, Im afraid this particular tool doesn´t exist, most of them yes but not everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Well these days app analysis is very important and are of great help. There are large number of analytics tools available. Some of them are free some of them are paid.

below are some of them

1. [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/)
2. [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/)
3. [Heatmaps](https://heatmaps.io/)

These are few which are used most. For most list visit this [link](http://www.mobyaffiliates.com/blog/list-mobile-app-analytics-tools/)

Hope this will help you. happy coding :)